# Read URL string from .xcconfig file in code

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, plist, xcconfig

How can I load URL string value from `.xcconfig` file in code? I have custom string property in it:

```
BASE_URL = "https://test.custom.com/api/4.0/"
```

I need to load this URL in code, so I added in `Info.plist` file this:

```
<key>TSBaseURL</key>
<string>$(BASE_URL)</string>
```

But when I tried to load this value from code, I get only trimmed value, because Xcode thinks, that `//` characters means commentary:

```
let baseURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["TSBaseURL"] as? String
```

returns

```
https:
```

I found this [technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2175/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004415-CH1-TNTAG3) from Apple, but I can't solve my problem with it. So exists any solution, how to load URL string from `.xcconfig` file?

Comment: This question is maybe duplicated, but original question is not answered, so why not to ask again and start up some discussion ...

Comment: It is the same question (unless I am mistaken) and the original has 4 answers. Did you try them? If they don't work then you can leave a comment and ask for clarification. And if someone finds a better solution then it should be added to the original.